# How to show changes in frontend when backend is edited

Tags: mongodb, flutter, httpresponse, future, state-management

I am using a mongodb database with backend based on NodeJS. I am calling one api to show a list of task (custom class) in front end and calling another API to delete a task. I want to read the list of task again when a task is deleted. How do I do that?

Function to get a list of tasks

```
Future<List<Task>> listOfTask() async {
    List<Task> result;
    try {
      final response = await http.get('api link');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Task> taskList = response.body.map<Task>((entry) {
          return Task.fromJson(entry);
        }).toList();
        result = taskList;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Getting the list of tasks in initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    DatabaseServices().listOfTask().then((value) {
      setState(() {listOfTask = value;});
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Function to delete task

```
  Future<http.Response> taskDelete(task) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.delete('api link');
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: " + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Deleting task from frontend

```
onPressed: () async {
  dynamic result = await DatabaseServices(token: token).taskDelete(task);  
},
```

How do I make sure the list of task is updated once I click delete. (Note: the Function to get task list and delete works)

Comment: Just call the API to read the list again when the API to delete the data returns success.

Comment: Can I use stream builder for this? But it doesnt seem to update